# locked out of local wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm extremely new to WP (been using it for about a week). I finished making my site locally using MAMP. I then wanted to move my local site to my web site. So I followed these instructions: http://easyfastwordpress.com/developing-locally-with-mamp-and-wordpress/ and by the time I got to step 8 I couldn't get into phpMyAdmin said it was unable to find database. I've read some threads on fixing this but none have worked as I can't remember my original settings. I've tried this method: http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Changing_the_URL_directly_in_the_database but since I don't recall my original siteURL and homeURL I don't know what to change them to. Please tell me there's a way to fix this! I worked so hard on stylizing my custom theme and I really can't afford to lose everything. Thanks!

Comment: Your provider manages your database. Should ask him or look for something in the settings of your customer admin panel for username, password, server and database name. Another option would be just to sign on wordpress.com and let them host your blog. You can out your own theme into it afaik.

Comment: Dan, I'm only trying to recover what I had going on my local machine. I'm using wordpress 3.6 and MAMP 2.1.3

Comment: _"error establishing connection with database"_ means you did not put the correct database credentials into config.php!

Answer (score 1):

Are you saying you forgot your password, you can get it from wp-config.php in the root folder of wordpress, did you forget your original url, if your dashboard is working its easy otherwise select the table wp_options and look for "siteurl" as the option_name and change the option_value for that particular option

Comment: Thanks for your reply skv. I remember my password. But I did forget my original url & my dashboard is not working because of that I'm assuming. I can't even get to the login page - an error message pops up saying "error establishing connection with database". My guess is that I need to go back into the database (through phpmyadmin) I was using locally through MAMP and change a few things, but I'm not sure what to change. I really need some help! Thanks!